# export column groups to excel

Tags: excel, datatable, export

I'm trying to know how to export a datatable with column groups into excel with the correct format. I'm using icefaces datatable, but with primefaces datatable it will be the same.

header has a recursive structure, so you can parse like xml file, but I can't see the way to reflect into excel file, just using jxl or poi.

I suppose somebody have the needs to export column groups into excel and right now I can't find a tool for do this.

Any idea??

Thanks

Comment: by "column groups" did you mean HTML tables with **colspan** attribute => Excel **Merge Cells**?

Comment: resolved: http://davisoski.blogspot.com.es/